# Обращение к объекту, как к массиву

Tags: javascript, объекты, index

Есть ли простой способ обратиться к ключу объекта по его индексу? Может в Underscore есть магические методы?

Вопрос возник на фоне такой задачи. Есть объект:

```
plane: {
    432: {
        columns: {
            543: {
                name: 'lolo'
            },
            984: {
                name: 'lala'
            },
            ...
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

Где среди n-го количества plane, и n-го количества column нужно выбрать первый plane и первый column внутри него.

Как сделать это проще всего?

Comment: Порядок ключов нет, так что нет такого понятия "ключ объекта по индексу". В `for(var key in obj)`, например, любой ключ может выть первым.

Comment: @PeterOlson, считаем что порядок лексикографический

Comment: @PeterOlson, ES6 определяет порядок. И по факту в браузерах оно уже более-менее так по историческим причинам. Сначала ключи, являющиеся целыми положительными числами по возрастанию, затем всё остальное в порядке добавления. Вроде был ещё альтернативный вариант в каких-то браузерах, но если все ключи являются целыми положительными числами и добавлены в порядке возрастания, то переживать не стоит - везде будет одинаково.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хотя ES6 [обеспечивает определённый порядок ключей при обходе](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-ownpropertykeys), гораздо правильнее и удобнее использовать массив, положив тот ключ внутрь объекта, например, в поле id.

---

Но если уж очень хочется, то можно сделать так (как-нибудь сократив название):

```
Object.prototype.getByKeyIndex = function (i) {
  var key = Object.keys(this)[i];
  return key && this[key];
}
```

Тогда на объекте из вопроса будет такое:

```
plane.getByKeyIndex(0).columns.getByKeyIndex(1).name
// "lala"
```

Вроде, более-менее нормально выглядит.

---

Ключ сохраняется в переменную и проверяется, чтобы в таком варианте получилось undefined:

```
({ undefined: 42 }).getByKeyIndex(256)
```

---

> Я новичок и хочу у Вас спросить - хорошо ли изменять прототип нативных объектов? Что будет если я добавлю метод, а после кто-то другой тоже Ваш ответ увидит и решит добавить свой, но с таким же методом?

В большинстве случаев изменять прототип Object'а не очень хорошо. Но для защиты от прототипных свойств принято фильтровать for-in через hasOwnProperty. Другой вариант - добавлять в прототип не так, как это сделал я, а через скрытое свойство, чтобы оно не перебиралось.

Если двое добавили одинаковое свойство, то одно из них перезапишет другое. По идее, последнее добавленное должно перезаписать предыдущее, но можно пошаманить с readonly, чтобы осталось более раннее. В любом случае, такая ситуация заведомо плохая и лучше в неё не попадать.

Если двое добавят одну и ту же функцию под разными именами, то будет две функции. Тут вроде всё очевидно и вопросов вызывать не должно.

Что касается того, стоит ли изменять прототип. Если это изменение упростит половину кода, то, на мой взгляд, это оправдано. Если же это делается ради одной функции, то, скорее всего, нет. Для любых глобальных изменений стоит проявлять разумность и осторожность.

Comment: Я новичок и хочу у Вас спросить - хорошо ли изменять прототип нативных объектов? Что будет если я добавлю метод, а после кто-то другой тоже Ваш ответ увидит и решит добавить свой, но с таким же методом?

Comment: @shatal, обновил ответ.

Comment: @MakarovAV, ES6 уже вышел. Лучше было бы ссылку на то же самое в окончательной спецификации.

Comment: @Qwertiy, добавил

Comment: Да, в этом случае действительно лучше использовать массив, но обычно я использую хэш-таблицу, т.к. в большинстве случаев с ней удобней работать, избегая различных методов поиска Underscore.

Answer (score 2):

`Object.keys(obj)[index]` например, где `obj` - объект в котором мы ищем.

Не вполне ослоустойчиво, будет работать в `IE 9+`.

Можно использовать `_.keys(obj)[index]` из underscore, это все сократит на пару символов =).

Кстати я не уверен, что лексикографический (да и вообще какой-то) порядок ключей нам гарантирован при этом, скорее всего массив ключей надо дополнительно сортировать.

Comment: Да, именно так делаю сейчас, но с каждым следующим уровнем вложенности это выглядит все хуже

Comment: @Harvey пока выглядит так, что Вам стоит как-то переработать ваше решение архитектурно а не искать какой-то грязный хак для частной проблемы)

Comment: @Harvey, тут кстати стоит уточнить, вам объект откуда-то приходит "как есть" и перестраивать его - проблема?

Comment: да, вы правы, с архитектурой тут наверное не все хорошо для указанного случая, но для других манипуляций она как раз удобна, т.к. можно обратиться к объекту напрямую по id без использования поисковых методов, если бы это был массив.
Чаще взвешиваю "на глаз" все за и против :), прежде чем решить будет ли  коллекция массивом или хэш-таблицей

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: Порядок ключей в объекте JS не гарантируется. Для сохранения порядка лучше юзать массив.

---

**Из личного опыта**:

Браузеры стараются придерживаться того порядка полей, в котором они были определены.

Но на это рассчитывать не стоит. Например, при общении с сервером через WebApi порядок может сбится.

Практический пример: в `python` объекты JSON преобразуется в словарь `dict`. А в нем уж точно порядок полей не сохраняется и может поменятся произвольно при сериализации обратно в JSON.

Объекты JS - это хеш-таблицы, т.е. пары ключ-значение. Порядок пар в такой структуре данных не имеет значения. Они удобны для обращения по ключу со сложностью O(1) (т.е. вне зависимости от числа этих пар).

---

**Из спецификации**:

1. Порядок ключей в [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) такой же, как при перечислении через `for...in`.
2. В описании же [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) сказано `in arbitrary order`, что значит "в произвольном порядке".

---

**Косвенные признаки**:

1. В консоли Chrome и во время отладки свойства идут в алфавитном порядке.
   А при проходе через `for...in` - в порядке определения.
   То, что хром так пренебрежительно относится к порядку ключей объекта, говорит о том, что он не имеет никакого значения.
2. В JS нет никаких явных способов изменить порядок полей. Или хотя бы вставить поле в середину объекта.

Comment: Спасибо за правку ответа, так и вправду лучше.

Comment: Если уж пишете эталонный ответ, то стоит добавить что "in arbitrary order" в es6-спеке таки заменен на конкретный порядок, как уже указал в своем ответе Qwertiy

Comment: Выше ответы лучше, мой далек до эталонного. Просто облагородил куда менее полезный ответ.

Comment: Детерменированный порядок полей в ES 2015 (когда он еще будет практически) все еще не решает проблему конвертации JSON через другие языки (python в моем случае). Поэтому надо юзать массив. 100% рабочий способ.

Answer (score 0):

```
var key = function(obj, n) {
    return obj[Object.keys(obj)[n]];
}

key(key(d, 0), 0);
```

Если вы хотите порядок сохранять, то передалайте на массивы:

```
plane: [{
    432: {
        columns: [{
            543: {
                name: 'lolo'
            },
            984: {
                name: 'lala'
            },
            ...
        },
        ...
        ]
    },
    ...
},    
...
]
```

Comment: Баг: `key({undefined:42}, 256)` - получится `42`.