# Сортировка объекта в javascript

Tags: javascript

Есть такой объект:

```
data['params']['last_name']['property_xxc'] = 'abcd';
data['params']['last_name']['sort_index'] = 2;
data['params']['name']['property_erw'] = 'abcd';
data['params']['name']['sort_index'] = 5;
data['params']['date']['property_xxc'] = 'abcd';
data['params']['date']['sort_index'] = 3;
```

Этот объект с такой глубокой вложенностью, нужно отсортировать по полу `sort_index`, в итоге нужно получить такой объект:

```
data['params']['name']['property_erw'] = 'abcd';
data['params']['name']['sort_index'] = 5;
data['params']['date']['property_xxc'] = 'abcd';
data['params']['date']['sort_index'] = 3;
data['params']['last_name']['property_xxc'] = 'abcd';
data['params']['last_name']['sort_index'] = 2;
```

Пробовал отсортировать с помощью `sort()` так:

```
var compareData = (a, b) =>{
     return a.sort_index - b.sort_index;
};
```

Но, ничего не вышло. Подскажите как сделать такую сортировку?

Comment: А с чего вы решили, что ваш **объект** будет сортироваться методом `sort`?

Comment: т.е. надо изменить порядок следования свойств в объекте. для чего это надо?

Comment: Вам же ответили, что сортировка полей в объекте не имеет смысла, а сортировка вывода `JSON.stringify` не гарантируется. Если вам нужна гарантированная сортировка, почему бы не поменять формат данных на сортируемый?

Comment: Первый и второй объекты у вас идентичны. Сортировка текстового представления нестабильна и когда-нибудь может привести к плавающему багу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если надо изменить порядок следования свойств в объекте и в коде на javascript есть следующие строки

```
data['params']['last_name']['property_xxc'] = 'abcd';
data['params']['last_name']['sort_index'] = 2;
data['params']['name']['property_erw'] = 'abcd';
data['params']['name']['sort_index'] = 5;
data['params']['date']['property_xxc'] = 'abcd';
data['params']['date']['sort_index'] = 3;
```

то это значит, что в памяти находится следующий объект:

```
var data = {
    'params': {
        'last_name': {
            'property_xxc': 'abcd',
            'sort_index': 2
        },
        'name': {
            'property_erw': 'abcd',
            'sort_index': 5
        },
        'date': {
            'property_xxc': 'abcd',
            'sort_index': 3
        }
    }
};
```

Проверить это легко. Например, так

```
try { data['params']['last_name']['property_xxc'] = 'abcd'; } 
catch(e) { alert(e); }   // alert не появится, значит все правильно
```

Если надо изменить порядок следования свойств в этом объекте, то можно сделать так:

```
var result = { 'params': {} };
Object.keys(data.params).sort(function (a, b) {
    return data.params[b].sort_index - data.params[a].sort_index;
}).forEach(function (v) { result.params[v] = data.params[v]; });
```

В result получим свойства в необходимом порядке. Это можно проверить, вызвав `JSON.stringify(result)`, получим

```
{
  "params": {
     "name": {
        "property_erw": "abcd",
        "sort_index": 5
     },
     "date": {
        "property_xxc": "abcd",
        "sort_index": 3
     },
     "last_name": {
        "property_xxc": "abcd",
        "sort_index": 2
     }
   }
}
```

Хотя это и можно сделать, но менять порядок свойств в объекте обычно не надо, но может понадобиться, например, для кодогенерации. Например, если надо сериализовать объект в JSON файл, который будет редактироваться вручную (например, в Visual Studio 2015 используются конфигурационные файлы project.json).

Comment: так как спецификацией не гарантируется порядок обхода свойств в объекте, то данная реализация будет зависеть от браузера в котором запускается, так как любой браузер может использовать любой порядок обхода полей объекта.

Comment: @Grundy _"данная реализация будет зависеть от браузера"_ -- проверял в Edge. работает. но я так и не понял для чего такое может понадобиться? если для вывода данных, то нужно данные сортировать, а не свойства в объекте.

Comment: То что где-то этот код работает не гарантирует что это будет работать _везде и всегда_. Единственное что не меняется -- спецификация, а она говорит, что порядок свойств не гарантирован

Comment: @DmitriySimushev _"То что где-то этот код работает не гарантирует что это будет работать везде и всегда."_ -- да, ничто не вечно под Луной. но не будем обобщать. есть вопрос. и хотя непонятно для чего он нужен, но тем не менее, у меня в ответе сохранены все уровни вложенности, и делается то, что надо. и еще раз хочу обратить внимание на ой вопрос: для чего вообще надо сортировать порядок свойств в объекте? мой ответ: это делать не надо.

Comment: @Grundy, ES6 гарантирует. Но есть одна фишечка про int32-ключи. В целом, если все ключи нечисловые, то во всех браузерах (даже старых) порядок будет одинаковый. Если есть числовые, то отсортировать принципиально невозможно.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, см. комментарий выше.

Comment: @Qwertiy, а можешь место гарантирования показать в спеке?

Comment: @Grundy, http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/436060/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy: Тогда по идее легко сваять контрпример, на котором код не сработает?

Comment: @VladD, не понял. Код правильный, если имена полей не int32. О каком контр-примере речь?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну, сделать объект частично с числовыми ключами ("1", "1а", "2"), попытаться отсортировать, получить фэйл.

Comment: @VladD, а зачем в вопросе про сортировку строк давать контрпример с числами?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Это ж не число, это ж строка "1" :)

Comment: @VladD, все ключи строки.. Или символы :D

Answer (score 9):

Ваша структура данных — это не массив, а **объект**. Порядок следования элементов в объекте не гарантирован спецификацией (по крайней мере [до ES2015](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-ownpropertykeys) и даже там есть тонкости с целочисленными ключами), поэтому в общем случае его сортировка не имеет смысла. Попытка вызвать метод `sort` у объекта закончится неудачей, поскольку у него попросту нет такого метода.

Как следствие, если вы хотите сортировать ваши данные, то вам лучше сначала перейти от объекта к массиву, а уже потом выполнять сортировку, используя [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). Это можно сделать, например, так:

```
var data = {
    'params': [
        {
            'name': 'last_name',
            'property_xxc': 'abcd',
            'sort_index': 2
        },
        {
            'name': 'name',
            'property_erw': 'abcd',
            'sort_index': 5
        },
        {
            'name': 'date',
            'property_xxc': 'abcd',
            'sort_index': 3
        }
    ]
}

data.params.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.sort_index - b.sort_index;
});

console.dir(data);
```

Comment: @Stack, скорее всего код в вопросе работает, а также скорее всего это php. так что к ответу действительно никак не относится, так как в ответе приведен пример нужной структуры

Comment: @Grundy _"скорее всего это php."_ -- в вопросе тег [javascript]. посмотрите мой ответ. добавил объяснение в начало.

Comment: @Stack, нужен комментарий автора. В любом случае, в ответе указана структура с которой нужно работать **вместо** той что указана в вопросе. Таким образом ваш первый комментарий выдрал строку из вопроса по заполнению объекта, а скорее всего тут просто показано чем равно конкретное поле, так как автор не догадался json выложить,  а так же не указано что это за data и откуда получается, и я все больше уверен что это именно пример заполнения в php а не в яваскрипте, и пытается ее применить к другой структуре указанной в ответе, это не будет работать, так как структура изменена и **уже** заполнена.

Comment: @Grundy _"в ответе указана структура с которой нужно работать вместо той что указана в вопросе."_ -- то что нужно автору написано в вопросе. посмотрите внимательно. name, date, last_name - это ссылки на объекты со своими свойствами. а в ответе один уровень вложенности убрали и пытаются доказать, что так правильно.

Comment: @Stack, там не убрали уровень вложенности, там заменили объект `params` на **массив** `params` а так же объяснили почему.

Comment: @Grundy _"ваш первый комментарий выдрал строку из вопроса по заполнению объекта, а скорее всего тут просто показано чем равно конкретное поле, так как автор не догадался json выложить"_ -- вот так прямо и выдрал?) хотите сказать, что восстановить структуру объекта по вызовам к его свойствам невозможно?)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35014/discussion-between-grundy-and-stack).

Comment: `Ваша структура данных - это не массив, а объект.`
 В теме нет речи про массивы
`скорее всего код в вопросе работает, а также скорее всего это php` 
 метки смотрите к какому языку относится  
P.S. в массиве что приведена в данном ответе искревлена структура что есть в шапке

Comment: @sanu0074, да я видел, что нет упоминания о массиве. **Но** порядок следования ключей в объекте не гарантирован, следовательно нельзя говорить о сортировке

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev, да, я это уже понял, спасибо)

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/436060/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy, обновил ответ

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы)