# Как отсортировать объект по нескольким параметрам при помощи обертки sort (js)

Tags: javascript, сортировка

Есть объект, содержащий объекты с параметрами следующего вида:

```
"apartments": {
"3-112": {
  "cpm": 0,
  "f": 12,
  "s": 3,
  "b": 3,
  "tc": 0,
  "sq": 28.18,
  "n": 112,
  "st": 0,
  "rc": " Студии"
},
"1-501": {
  "cpm": 0,
  "f": 21,
  "s": 1,
  "b": 1,
  "tc": 0,
  "sq": 55.1,
  "n": 501,
  "st": 0,
  "rc": "2-комнатные"
},
"1-461": {
  "cpm": 0,
  "f": 18,
  "s": 1,
  "b": 1,
  "tc": 0,
  "sq": 30.55,
  "n": 461,
  "st": 0,
  "rc": " Студии"
},
}
```

**Задача: сделать выборку по параметрам f, tc, sq.**
Диапазон вводимых на входе переменных может быть любой.

Задачу решил довольно кустарным способом:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

function sortApartments(floorFrom, floorTo, priceFrom, priceTo, areaFrom, areaTo) {
var sorted = {};

$.getJSON('http://localhost:3000/data/apartaments--db.json', function(json){
  var apartments = json['apartments'];

  for(var key in apartments) {
    for(var prop in apartments[key]) {
      if((apartments[key]['f'] >= floorFrom && apartments[key]['f'] <= floorTo)
        && (apartments[key]['tc'] >= priceFrom && apartments[key]['tc'] <= priceTo) 
        && (apartments[key]['sq'] >= areaFrom && apartments[key]['sq'] <= areaTo)) {
        sorted[key] = apartments[key];
      }
    }
  }
});
return sorted;
};

  console.log(sortApartments(1, 50, 2000000, 3000000, 0, 1000));

}); // ready end
```

Как решить данную задачу при помощи sort?

Comment: а каким боком тут sort вообще?

Comment: Сортировку или фильтрацию?

Comment: _Как решить данную задачу при помощи sort?_ - никак

Answer (score 1):

Вообще, сама идея сортировать свойства объекта - так себе. Лучше подумать и сделать что-то нормальное. Но если уж очень надо, то можно так:

1. Убеждаемся (программист обещает?), что объект не содержит числовых ключей.
   Если содержит, то задача невыполнима.
2. Превращаем объект в массив при помощи `Object.entries`, его полифила или аналогичного своего кода.
3. Сортируем массив по нескольким полям, как рассказано в [соответствующем ответе](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/432370/178988).
4. Если нас устраивает новый объект, то создаём пустой объект.
   Если нам обязательно сделать замену внутри того же самого объекта, то удаляем из него все свойства при помощи `delete`.
5. Проходим по отсортированному массиву добавляем соответствующие свойства в объект, полученный на шаге 4.

Comment: но его текущий код **не сортирует**, а выбирает нужные поля в отдельный объект

Comment: @Grundy, но я не читал его код... Есть вопрос в заголовке - я на него и ответил.

Comment: И не угадал :-) мало ли что он в заголовке понаписал

Comment: @Grundy, ну может кому-нибудь ещё пригодится :)

Comment: У нас же уже был ответ про сортировку полей в объекте

Comment: @Grundy, не уверен... Что-то было, но что и где  - не помню. Там вроде больше к обсуждению порядка свойств свелось?

Comment: [вот например](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/487160/186999)

Comment: @Grundy, да, годится :)

Comment: закрыть как дубликат? :-)

Comment: @Grundy, ну этот более широкий - я бы оставил.

Comment: этот, по большому счету, вообще не про сортировку :)

Answer (score 1):

Сначала объявляем функцию

```
function compareR(a, b) {
      if (a.f> b.f)
           return -1;
      if (a.f< b.f) 
           return 1;
      if (a.tc> b.tc)
           return -1;
      if (a.tc< b.tc) 
           return 1;    
      if (a.sq> b.sq)
           return -1;
      if (a.sq< b.sq) 
           return 1;    
       return 0;
}
```

(тут я подразумеваю, что доступ до полей простой)

А потом просто вызываем сортировку массива (с нашей функцией) `MyArray.sort(compareR);`